# Using flex-box with Slick-carousel, width = 0 & first slide is hidden

Tags: width, flexbox, carousel, hidden, slick.js

When first loading the slick-carousel while using flex-boxes, the width of the slick-slide and the slick-track are set to 0 which hides the first slide until it triggers the next slide.  If there is only one slide, it's hidden and will never show unless the window is manually resized.

Answer (score 0):

**First wrap your carousel with a container:**

```css
.myContainer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer">
     <div class="myCarousel" (click)="navigate()"></div>
</div>
```

**Next, be sure is to have min-height & min-width set to 0 for the .slick-slider.**

**CSS:**
*note the changes from the default slick-carousel styles are commented*

```css
// new definition
.slick-slider {
    min-height: 1px; 
    min-width: 1px;
}

.slick-slide {
    float: left;

    [dir="rtl"] {
        float: right;
    }
    img {
        display: block;
    }
    &.slick-loading img {
        display: none;
    }

    display: none;

    &.dragging img {
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .slick-initialized {
        display: block;
        // set height and width
        height: 100%; // helps to fix the loading issue when using flex-box - stretches slide vertically
        width: 100% !important;  // helps to fix the loading issue when using flex-box - shows slide upon load
    }

    .slick-loading {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .slick-vertical {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
}

.slick-track {
     position: relative;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     display: block;
     // set height
     width: 100% !important;  //  helps to fix the loading issue when using flex-box

     &:before,
     &:after {
         content: "";
         display: table;
     }

     &:after {
         clear: both;
     }

     .slick-loading {
         visibility: hidden;
     }
 }

.slick-initialized {
    display: block;
    // set height and width
    height: 100%; // helps to fix the loading issue when using flex-box - stretches slide vertically
    width: 100% !important;  // helps to fix the loading issue when using flex-box - shows slide upon load
}

.slick-loading {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-vertical {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

**Finally, make sure you have defined the responsive setting when initializing your slick-slider:**

```html
// initialize carousel
private initializeCarouselSettings(){
    this.carousel.slick({
        accessibility: false,
        autoplay: false,
        arrows: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        pauseOnFocus: false,
        draggable: false,
        swipe: false,
        touchMove: false,
        centerMode: true,
        fade: this.isTransitionTypeFade(),
        autoplaySpeed: this.getSlideInterval(),
        speed: this.getSpeedValue(),
        responsive: [ // fixes the loading issue when using flex-box
            {
                breakpoint: 1024,
                settings: {
                    mobileFirst: false,
                    infinite: true,
                    speed: this.getSpeedValue(),
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    centerMode: true,
                    variableWidth: false,
                    focusOnSelect: false
                }
            }
        ]
   });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the usage of the & in these selectors?

.slick-loading & {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .slick-vertical & {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }

To me it does not give any meaning when there is no selector after the &...

Comment: You are correct.  Normally, the & is used when nesting.  It's usually used after a class like: .some-class { &.another-class{} }.  So, good catch,  the & after the class without a nested class is unnecessary.